# how to pass sparql query variable in ahref to publish on new page

Tags: php, sparql

Actually I have 2 sparql queries one fetch result of all people and display them by using html code in that code I have

```
   echo '<td><span >    
     <a href="'.( str_replace(" ", "-",$row->name)) .'" >'.$row->name 
       .'    
    </a> 
      </span></td>';
```

which directs to page with specific person name when clicked.
Now for every person to have his own details on new page I have another query

```
    if (isset($_GET[$row->name])) {

        $person = $sparql->query(' SELECT ?p ?o WHERE {   
     [ foaf:name "'.$row->name.'" ] ?p ?o}'   );

         echo $person->dump();
    }
```

I want to display these query results to new page once any person name is clicked. Nothing is happing i dont know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Looks like you're mixing HTML and PHP... can you provide more code?

Comment: Also, check out both of these links: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask & https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks Dammeul but I am stuck any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Sparql, however, I would code what you have like this:

```
echo '<td><span><a href="'. str_replace(" ", "-",$row->name) . '">' . $row->name .'</a></span></td>';

if (isset($_GET[$row->name])) {
   $person = $sparql->query('SELECT ?p ?o WHERE {[ foaf:name "'.$row->name.'" ] ?p ?o}');
   echo $person->dump();
}
```

`str_replace()` had extra brackets around it, the rest is the same, could be worth trying the echo as I have given it to you.

Also, turn on errors:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

This will help determine the exact issue.

Comment: Warning: Illegal offset type in isset or empty. this warning I am getting

Comment: it returns all the names coming from SPARQL query.